# Unable to analyse Throughput Performance of One API which has been migrated to new platform

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, throughput, jmeter-4.0

I have checking the performance one APIs which is performing in two systems therefore as the api has been migrated to new system i am doing the performance comparison from old system

Statistics as shown below:
 
New System:
 
Thread  -25
Ramp-up ~25
Avg -8sec
Median - 7.8
95th percentile  -  8.8 sec
Throughput  - 0.39

Old System:
 
Thread  -25
Ramp-up ~25
Avg -10 sec
Median - 10
95th percentile - 10
Throughput  - 0.74

Here we can observe that the New System has taken less time for 25 Threads than old system but throughput is more Old System.

But Old System has Taken more time

I am confused about the throughput which system is more efficient ?

One which has taken less time should have more throughput but here the lesser time taken has less throughput which makes me confused to understand the performance??

can anyone help me here???

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html):

> Throughput is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
>
> The formula is: `Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time)`

So double check total test duration for both test executions, my expectation is that the "new system test" took longer.

With regards to the reason I cannot state anything meaningful without seeing the full .jtl results files for both executions, I can only assume that it could be one very long request in the "new system" test or you're having a [Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer) with random [think time](https://medium.com/@malith.jayasinghe/performance-testing-with-a-think-time-64b6b737e3f9) somewhere in your test.